# Example of two non-homeomorphic spaces with two continual mappings between them

Tags: general-topology, continuity

My question is about to find to topological spaces $(X,\tau_X),(Y,\tau_Y)$ that are non-homeomorphic but there exist two bijective functions $f:X\to Y, f \in C(X \to Y)$ and $g:Y \to X, g \in C(Y \to X)$.

Comment: This has been answered on MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30661/non-homeomorphic-spaces-that-have-continuous-bijections-between-them/251028.  I'm not sure what to do in terms of closing it.  In any event, I really like Jens Reinhold's answer there.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Perhaps it is a question for meta what to do if a question is a duplicate, but a duplicate **not in this forum**.